# Bash script using awk in for loop

Tags: bash, awk

```
for i in $LIST
do
  CFG=`ssh $i "cat log.txt|awk '{print $2}'"`
  for j in $CFG
  do
    echo $j
  done
done
```

Say I want to print 2nd field in the log file on a couple remote host. In above script, print $2 doesn't work. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Using `cat` is unnecessary: `CFG=$(ssh $i "awk '{print $2}' log.txt")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
for i in $LIST
do
  ssh $i "cat log.txt|awk '{print \$2}'"
done
```

Comment: thanks, but I just edited my question again. Now backslash doesn't work. Can you please look into it again?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. Are you just trying to output the 2nd column of "log.txt" for each host in $LIST?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the number of shell expansions and type of quoting multiple backslash escapes are needed:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' log.txt # none
ssh $server "awk '{ print \$2 }' log.txt" # one
CFG=`ssh $server "awk '{ print \\$2 }' log.txt"` # two
CFG=$(ssh $server "awk '{ print \$2 }' log.txt") # one (!)
```

As a trick you can put a space between the dollar sign and the two to prevent all $ expansion. Awk will still glue it together:

```
  CFG=`ssh $i "cat log.txt|awk '{print $ 2}'"`
```

Comment: This answer is so helpful! Thanks schot!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're escaping the `$2` from the shell - the ssh command you end up sending right now is something like this: `ssh listvalue cat log.txt|awk '{print }'`

Answer (score 1):

```
for server in $LIST
do
   ssh "$server" 'awk "{print $2}" log.txt'
done
```

- Carefully watch the location of the `single-quote` and the `double-quote`.
- Bash tries to expand variables (`words beginning with $`) inside double-quote (`"`).
- Single-quote (`'`) stops Bash from looking for variables inside.
- As **`user131527`** and **`psj`** suggested, escaping `$2` with `\` should also have worked (depending on how your Bash is configured).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put awk in a double for loop

`for i in 1 2 3 4;do
        for j in $\(ls | awk -v I=$i '{print $I}');
          echo $j
        done;
 done`

Comment: Be sure to format your code in your answer to make it look like code `\`\`\``

Comment: @unmultimedio No. SO uses four spaces at the beginning of all lines within a codeblock

Comment: You're right, it's `\`code\`` for code-line and 4 spaces for code-block

Answer (score 0):

Lose the cat. Its useless..

```
for server in $LIST
do
  ssh "$server" "awk '{print \$2}' log.txt"
don
```